# Ruby on Rails Symbol not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-big-sur, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have the following error; when I run the application at the moment of rendering this happens

```sh
unknown@mini Project.V1 % bundle exec rails s
DEPRECATION WARNING: axlsx_rails has been renamed to caxlsx_rails. See http://github.com/caxlsx
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.7.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.2 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2021-09-02 20:47:51 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.haml within layouts/login
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __ZN2v82V813InitializeICUEPKc
  Referenced from: /Users/unknown/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_racer-0.2.9/lib/mini_racer_extension.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN2v82V813InitializeICUEPKc
  Referenced from: /Users/unknown/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mini_racer-0.2.9/lib/mini_racer_extension.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

zsh: abort      bundle exec rails s
```

This only occurs when rendering views from the server; here are details of the operating system and hardware (`Mac Mini M1`)

### OS

```sh
unknown@mini Project.V1 % ruby --version
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [-darwin20]

unknown@mini Project.V1 % rails --version
Rails 5.0.7.2

unknown@mini Project.V1 % sw_vers        
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.5.2
BuildVersion:   20G95

unknown@mini Project.V1 % uname          
Darwin
```

Any help or ideas are welcome, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this issue has already been reported on `mini_racer` - Ref: https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer/issues/185

Try the solutions mentioned in the thread - [here](https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer/issues/185#issuecomment-769949258)

```
# Gemfile
gem 'mini_racer', github: 'rubyjs/mini_racer', branch: 'refs/pull/186/head'
# or
gem 'mini_racer', github: 'sqreen/mini_racer', branch: 'use-libv8-node'
```

or

Try the following version of mini_racer

```
gem 'mini_racer', '~> 0.4.0'
```